# Find count of transactions and customer where they have purchased one item along with something else SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table which has the transaction details of the customer:

```
Customernum   sls   unit    txn no   SKU      txn_date  
      1       10     30      567    903633   2019-02-01   yes
      1       20     30      567    123767   2019-02-01   yes
      1       50     40      567    126658   2019-03-01   yes
      1       10     40      345    773633   2019-02-10   yes
      1       12     30      345    965322   2019-02-10 
      1       10     50      678    838364   2019-02-15   yes
      1       10     70      975    983636   2019-02-28   yes
      2       11     80      910    903633   2019-02-11 
      2       11     90      910    566373   2019-02-12   yes
      3       11     62      855    678364   2019-02-12
```

I have another table which has the SKU:

```
sku     Desc
123767  APP
903633  CD
773633  APP
838364  APP
983636  APP
566373  APP
126658  APP
```

I need to find the transactions from the above transactions which has 903633 in the transaction along with the other SKU from the SKU table and transactions which have more than one of the SKU' from the above table.

So the two questions I am trying to anwer is :

- How many transactions included only 1 apparel item along with CD
- How many transactions included more than one apparel items with CD.

I have tried the below query but I have had no luck:

```
select a.Customernum, a.txnno, td.sku,
  case when ps.sku is not null
       then 'Yes'
       else 'No'
  end as is_sku,
  case when count(b.sku) over (partition by a.txnno) > 0
       then 'Yes'
       else 'No'
  end as has_sku
from table a
left join sku b on b.sku = a.sku;
```

I am expecting the below result:

Result 1- How many transactions included only 1 apparel item along with CD

```
customernum  txnno    unit    sls
 2           910       80      11
 2           910       90      11
 1           678       50      10
 1           975       70      10
```

Result 2- How many transactions included more than one apparel items with CD.

```
customernum  txnno    unit    sls
 1           567       30      10
 1           567       30      20
 1           567       40      50
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect for this sample data.

Comment: @GMB I have updated the question and included the results

Comment: Why is txnno 678 in the first resultset, while it this transaction does not involve sku 903633?

Comment: Also in the first resultset, txnno 975 has no other sku than 903633, so that does not qualify as *only 1 apparel item along with CD*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation.  The subquery counts the number of "app"s and "cd"s.  The outer filter to just one "cd" (you can use `>=` if you want at least one) and aggregates by the number of "app"s:

```
select num_app, count(*) as num_customers
from (select t.customernum,
             sum(case when s.desc = 'APP' then 1 else 0 end) as num_app,
             sum(case when s.desc = 'CD' then 1 else 0 end) as num_cd
      from transactions t join
           skus s
           on t.sku = s.sku
     ) c
where num_cd = 1
group by num_app
order by num_app;
```

Comment: I do not have Description in my data base, I have mentioned it only in this question for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with window functions.

The following query would give you all transactions that involve `sku` `903633` with exactly one other `sku`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        count(*) over(partition by txnno) cnt,
        max(case when sku = 903633 then 1 end) has_cd
    from mytable t
) t
where has_cd = 1 and cnt = 2
```

To get the transactions that involve sku `903633` and at least two other `sku`s, you can just change `cnt = 2` to `cnt > 2`.